# If Statement and For-loops - How to take only every 5th number?

Tags: vb.net, windows, if-statement, for-loop

What I'm trying to do is loop through the numbers 0 to 100 and check which ones are divisible by 5 and have that print to console, this is what I've done so far:

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()

    For i = 0 To 100
        If i / 5 =  Then
            Console.WriteLine(i)
        End If

    Next

    Console.ReadLine()


End Sub

End Module
```

I'm wondering if I'm able to have an If statement check with a range of numbers for example like this:

```
If i / 5 = 0 to 19 Then
```

Is that possible?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> like this: `If i / 5 = 0 to 19 Then ...`

You can use the `Step` argument in the [`For`-loop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z06z1kb.aspx):

```
For i As Int32 = 0 To 100 Step 5
    Console.WriteLine(i)
Next
```

If you want to check if a number is divisible by another number use the [`Mod` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se0w9esz.aspx):

```
If i Mod 5 = 0  Then
    Console.WriteLine(i)
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the MOD operator. It divides the numbers but returns only the reminder.

You can check if a number is divisible by 5 if `number MOD 5 = 0`

So your code can be like this:

```
For i = 0 To 100 
    If i Mod 5 = 0 Then 
        Console.WriteLine(i) 
    End If 
Next
```